What is Friction at the most fundamental level?
What is friction at the most fundamental level(quantum level or atomic level). There are 4 fundamental forces from each all other forces are derived . Basically all the forces are manifestations of these four fundamental forces right? So how can we explain the reason or occurence of friction or how does it work fundamentally?

Of interest? Friction at the nanoscale

The four fundamental forces are gravity, electromagnetism, the weak force, and the strong force. Almost everything you are familiar with is caused by gravity and electromagnetism.
Gravity holds you to the earth and makes planets orbit the Sun.
Electromagnetism has vast consequences. It holds electrons and nuclei together. This force, as governed by quantum mechanics, shapes the orbitals of the electrons. This determines all of chemistry and all properties of materials. Light is generated and absorbed by particles carrying an electric charge. Electricity is the movement of electric charge.
The strong and weak forces only affect things that are extremely close together. They have an effect inside the nucleus of atoms. The electrons are too far away to feel the force. The weak force is responsible for certain types of radioactive decay. The strong force holds protons inside the nucleus, overcoming the electric repulsion they exert on each other. These are the only commonplace effects you will see.
So friction is caused by electromagnetism. The inner workings of friction are complicated and not completely understood. Questions like this have been asked on this site before - Why does friction occur?. This one was closed as a duplicate of a couple others that don't address how it works microscopically. If you want to know more, Google tribology.
Mostly people work with the simple equation that calculates the force. And comment on how surprising it is that such a complicate phenomenon has such a simple equation. And thank goodness.
